# Confusion about two claims concerning interpolating polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials, interpolation

Here

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynominterpolation

under "Konvergenzverhalten" I found the following claim

If $f$ is analytic on $[a,b]$ and we have a sequence of sets of nodes at which $f$ is interpolated such that the maximal length approaches $0$ , then the sequence of interpolating polynomials uniformly converges to $f(x)$.

Here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon

the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+25x^2}$$ is given as an example that the interpolation error increases without bound if more and more equidistant nodes in the interval $[-1,1]$ are used to interpolate $f(x)$.

> Is this not a contradiction to the claim above since $f(x)$ is analytic and the lengths of the sequence of sets of nodes converges to $0$ ?

What do I miss ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+25x^2}$ is not analytic on $[-1,1]$ even though it is smooth there. Proving this directly in real variables is difficult, but with complex analysis it is quite simple to see because of the poles at $\pm i/5$.

Comment: It's not real analytic on all of $[-1,1]$ either. If you expand at zero (the simplest case, though it doesn't prove my claim by itself), the radius of convergence--whether you're in real variables or complex variables--is $1/5$, so the sum does not converge when $|x|>1/5$. In general if you expand at some $x_0 \in [-1,1]$ the radius of convergence is the distance from $x_0$ to $\pm i/5$. It is a remarkable fact that the radius of convergence of a *real* power series is equal to the distance from the point of expansion to the closest *complex* singularity.

Comment: But here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function  the following claim is made : "The reciprocal of an analytic function that is nowhere zero is analytic". Is this only true if the function is nowhere zero in the complex plane ?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Comment: personally I don't quite agree with the definition of @Ian. To me: $f$ is analytic a some point $a$ if it admits a power series expansion at that point of strictly positive radius of convergence $r_a>0$. $f$ is analytic on a set if it is analytic at every point in the set (but not necessarily with uniform radius of converce for the power-series).

Comment: It is true that it admits a power series expansion about each point in $[-1,1]$ with some positive radius of convergence, but there is no single expansion that converges over the whole region. So you are right that $\frac{1}{1+25x^2}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ i/5,-i/5 \}$, but Runge's phenomenon still happens because of the lack of a single expansion that is valid over all of $[-1,1]$. And one can see that by complex variable methods.

Comment: But yes, I didn't word it very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is correct for any polynomial interpolations in an interval  $[a,b]$ if the function is analytic in a complex ball of radius $r>3(b-a)/2$ and centered at $(a+b)/2$. When $r$ is a bit smaller convergence depends upon the choice of interpolation points. $r>(b-a)/2$ is in general necessary. This is not the case for the Cauchy function $f$ which has poles at $\pm i/5$ which is inside the corresponding ball. (I vaguely recall that you may even estimate the rate at which the interpolation diverges...)

Comment: Indeed, and on a disk centered at $(a+b)/2$ of sufficient large radius. As I tried to describe the minimal radius depends somewhat on the choice of interpolation points.